# Why I cant get nested data from mongodb in Jade?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, pug

I'm stuck trying to get to info about "product" and "channel" from my mongo object. But have **"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"** while looping through nested array of objects:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("579f14f0661cf39cc86c75be"),
    "category": "slim"
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("579f14f0661cf39cc86c75bf"),
            "country": "AT",
            "elems": [{
                "chanell": "ATD",
                "produkt": "prod A"
            }, {
                "chanell": "RTB",
                "produkt": "prod B"
            }, {
                "chanell": "SEO",
                "produkt": "prod C"
            }]
        } {
            "_id": ObjectId("579f14f0661cf39cc86c75c0"),
            "country": "DE",
            "elems": [{
                "chanell": "ATD",
                "produkt": "prod A"
            }, {
                "chanell": "RTB",
                "produkt": "prod B"
            }, {
                "chanell": "SEO",
                "produkt": "prod C"
            }]
        }
```

Jade query:

```
block content
  h3.
    Products
  div
    p First Pargraph
      - each item in productlist
        p Country: #{item.country}
          - each elem in item.elems
            p #{elem.channell}
            p #{elem.produkt}
```

Output:

```
TypeError: /var/www/html/projects/bartek/ang/produkty/public/views/productlist.jade:10
   8|       - each item in productlist 
   9|         p Country: #{item.country} 
 > 10|           - each elem in item.elems 
   11|             p #{elem.channell} 
   12|             p #{elem.produkt}

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

And my node code:

```
var collection = db.collection('slim');

        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else if (result.length) {
                res.render('productlist',{
                 'productlist' : result   
                })
            }
```

At level "country" everything works fine - country is displayed properly. Item "item.elems" alone shows array of objects:  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

Comment: You got two errors in your JSON. After `"slim"` should be a comma and the following object should have a key... like `...": "slim", "data": [{object},{object}],...` The objects of `data` should also be sepperated by comma. I tested it in a Pen: http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/QEVaLa

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot.